# Opencart Theme Products won't Press on Mobile

Tags: html, css, task-parallel-library, opencart

I have been installing an opencart theme for someone (version 2.1.0.2) and have had no problems yet until this situation with buttons not pressing on mobile.

Current site is at shop.amethysthaircollection.com

The buttons that will not press are the product photos. On PC, they work fine. I looked through the product.tpl and couldn't figure out what to change.

Please help here!

Answer (score 0):

I was on your product page for example here:
http://shop.amethysthaircollection.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50

And I noticed your image thumnbnail links kept giving an error that the image can't load (both on pc and mobile) when clicking on them. Then I took a look by hovering over the thumbnail images at what it's linking to, and it's not even linking to the image path. It's linking instead to: shop.amethysthaircollection.com/$product

Notice the $product at the end of that hyperlink?

Your html/tpl file is only showing this for the link:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="$product" title="Brazilian Diamond"> <img src="http://shop.amethysthaircollection.com/image/cache/catalog/Brazilian Diamond/new3-74x74.jpeg" title="Brazilian Diamond" alt="Brazilian Diamond"></a>
```

So that href part is not populating correctly with the image path. If you ended up messing with just the product.tpl file make sure that this part of the code shows:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
```

I believe you're issue is probably just the product.tpl file with that href having that error in it since you are trying to echo $product instead of echoing $popup.

I have no idea how this worked for you on a desktop when it just doesn't work on my end altogether because of that error in your tpl file. I hope this solves your issue. However, if it still doesn't work, then it means that you have an issue instead in your controller product.php file that it's populating it with $product. If this is the case, do a search in your controller's product.php file for "popup" and ensure the code isn't broken in there for all the popup-related lines (you can check it against the default/unaltered original opencart file, if you still have it to see if your changes broke something).